# Can't load css files from theme folder

Tags: laravel

I am trying to load css files from `themes` folder which is in the `root` directory. But 404 error is thrown in the console:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/theme/elite/css/mainie.css net::ERR_ABORTED
>   404 (Not Found)

The files are there and working fine on the shared hosting. After downloading the project to my localhost this happened. Must say that I cleared all the caches if that is somehow related with the issue.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Checked other solution in stackoverf and github but couldn't make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When properly set up (or when using `php artisan serve`), the root directory is not accessible by browsers. This is important for security.

Only files in the `public` directory can be accessed in the browser, so move your `themes` folder into that and it should all work.

Comment: (Also, decide if it's `themes` or `theme`. You use them interchangeably in your question.)

Comment: It's a typo. Thank you :)